# What is the big-O of this recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, big-o

We have a problem of size n

An algorithm that recursively solves a subproblem of size n − 1 and performs
a linear amount of work on the solution.

I tried using plug n chug and found that the big-O is n, linear, but that does not seem right to me. What else could I try?

Comment: is 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n linear just because each term is linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the recursion mentioned by you is:

- T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)

It implies that:

T(n) = kn + k(n-1) + k(n-2) + .. + k, which is equal to k * n * (n + 1) / 2.

So, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 2):

The people at Mathematics Stack Exchange will probably be able to do this better than I can, but I'll give it a shot.

The description of the algorithm is ambiguous, so there are two possibilities:

1. **The algorithm performs a constant amount of work for each subproblem.**
   In this case, the algorithm will in fact run in `O(n)` time (technically
   `2n`, but constant factors are ignored).
2. **The algorithm performs a linear amount of work for each subproblem.** 
   In this case, you're looking at a linear loop that does linear work each
   execution. `n` executions, `n` work per execution = `O(n^2)`.
   Obviously each successive execution does less work, and this would
   manifest in a recurrence relation solution as something around
   `T(n) = (1/2)n^2`, assuming I remember that pattern of problem right.

Comment: The wording of the problem seems to suggest the second interpretation (the algorithm calls itself on n-1 and then does a linear amount of work "on the solution" which suggests that there is a linear amount of work after the recursive call.